# Writing in flash is IO Mapped while reading from flash is Memory mapped...what could be the reasons

Tags: embedded, bootloader, spi, flash-memory

I am using Broadcom CFE(common framework enviorment) boot loader... the SOC is from Broadcom...and using Serial NOR Flash **N25Q032** as a bootstrap device. To read from the flash it is using memory map technique while to write it is  using SPI interface (IO mapped).

The reason behind such a design seems to me are as:

1. IO mapped reading/writing is blocking call so while reading to keep the CPU free, it is implemented using memory mapped.
2. It don't have an implementation to check tha... now mapped area in the RAM is modified so change the flash accordingly (means failing to implement memory mapped write) and its comparatively easy to use SPI interface (IO mapped) implementation to write the flash.

....Please explain what could be the reason behind such design....

Comment: @blueshift: I have updated the question plz find the details above.

Comment: I and pretty much everyone else reading your question don't know what the Broadcom code is, or how it maps memory or IO. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: You said it already, it's a bootstrap device. You want to be able to read and execute instructions from it without any problem for the CPU (so it must be memory mapped for reads). However, you would not want to accidentally write to your bootstrap device so having a non-memory mapped method to write to it gives you a degree of safety (from randwom writes caused by poor code).

Comment: If it uses a SPIFI bus to memory map the SPI device, then it probably only translates simple read/write accesses, while programming the flash is more involved.  Programming usually involves unlocking by writing special values to registers, erasing, and verifying (with marginal reads), working sector by sector (the size which varies), and relocking afterwards.  The SPIFI bus controller would have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition the serial memory cannot itself be memory mapped.  In this case I imagine (not having looked at the datasheet) that the NOR flash memory controller reads data into a dedicated memory mapped page in the micro-controller, so it is reading blocks serially into random-access memory.

When writing, the data is already in random-access memory, the NOR flash memory controller serializes that directly to the memory device.  It would make little sense to copy it from one memory mapped area to another just to then serialize it.

Comment: adding one more point, making the reading operation memory mapped is having the advantage  in increasing the reading speed....reading from memory is faster than reading from flash.